# Nokogiri undefined method 'attribute' nilClass

Tags: ruby, attributes, nokogiri

This may seem like an obvious question, but I am very new. I am trying to scrape [Rotten Tomatoes top 100 movie](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/) list for a simple CLI app. Everything goes fine until the hero.link line where I get a undefined method 'attribute' for nilClass. I'm just trying to get the value of the href of the title link. I've tried everything that I understand and more, but I just cannot figure out how to access what I want without using the attribute method.

However, when I get in with pry in the middle of the function, I'm able to type it in manually, it seems to work.

```
def new_with_rank
  self.get_top_page.css(".table tr").each do |e|
    hero = Top100::Movie.new
    hero.rank = e.css(".bold").text.delete!(".")
    binding.pry
    hero.rating = e.css(".tMeterScore").text.gsub!(/\u00A0/, "")
    hero.title = e.css(".unstyled").text
    hero.title.strip! #Don't know why I can't chain onto .text above
    hero.reviews = e.css("td.right.hidden-xs").text
    hero.link = e.css("td a").attribute("href").value
  end
  Top100::Movie.all.shift
  Top100::Movie.all
  binding.pry
end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Modify your pry line to this, 'binding.pry unless e.css("td a")'. Then you can see why e.css("td a") is nil. Looks like not all tr's have an anchor.

Comment: Please do not edit to remove your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future suggest such approach for debugging loops:

```
def new_with_rank
  self.get_top_page.css(".table tr").each do |e|
    begin
      hero = Top100::Movie.new
      hero.rank = e.css(".bold").text.delete!(".")
      hero.rating = e.css(".tMeterScore").text.gsub!(/\u00A0/, "")
      hero.title = e.css(".unstyled").text
      hero.title.strip! #Don't know why I can't chain onto .text above
      hero.reviews = e.css("td.right.hidden-xs").text
      hero.link = e.css("td a").attribute("href").value
    rescue => error
      puts error
      puts error.backtrace
      binding.pry
    end
  end
  Top100::Movie.all.shift
  Top100::Movie.all
end
```